# Report Viewer - non tabular display of data

Tags: reportviewer, ssrs-2008

Is there a way to display the results from a DataSet without a table control. If I try to use something like a label, and I use an expression for the label's value, I only see the first result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a List.  This will repeat through your data and allows for flexibility with your textboxes.